# Как мне сделать что бы в урл всегда был параметр языка?

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, роутер, маршрутизация

Здравствуйте!
у меня организована мультиязычность, и язык пишется в куки *lang = en*
когда в урл пишу *site.ru/lang=ru* то пишется в куки *lang = ru* и сайт работает на русском языке!
но вот потом параметр в урл исчезает!
Как мне сделать что бы в урл всегда был параметр языка?, например *site.ru/en/catalog.php* или *site.ru/ru/catalog.php* и т.д.

Как добиться мультиязычной маршрутизации???

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, задачу точнее. Одним из вариантов ее решения является использоваться mod_rewrite, чтобы он всегда преобразовывал ссылку, например, из вида _site.ru/ru/catalog.php_ в _site.ru/catalog.php?lang=ru_

Comment: @gecube как сделать так что бы: если в куках есть значение lang=en то и адрес страниц site.ru/en/catalog.php

Comment: @gecube Как добиться мультиязычной маршрутизации???

Answer (score 1):

Надо просто взять библиотеку которая может генерировать ссылки за тебя

**Например:**

https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute#named-routes-for-reverse-routing

```
<?php
    $router->get(['/{lang}/{name}', 'page_link'], function($lang, $name){
        return sprintf('Hello %s %s', $lang, $page);
    })
```

А в шаблоне будет:

```
<?php 

    $lang = $_COOKIE["lang"] ? $_COOKIE["lang"] : 'en';

    echo sprintf(
        "<a href='%s'>%s</a>",
        $router->route('page_link', [$lang, 'about']),
        'about'
    );
    // prints <a href='/en/about'>about</a>
```

А так же если вы поменяете путь
`/{lang}/{name}` -> `/static/{lang}/{name}`

То шаблоны менять не надо!

Подойдет любая библиотека которая так умеет ...

их мого: https://www.google.ca/search?q=php+router+library

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя есть файл который в каждой странице сайта включается к скрипту, то внутри него устанавливай кука `setcookie("lang", 'ru');`

Comment: как сделать так что бы: если в куках есть значение lang=en то и адрес страниц site.ru/en/catalog.php

Comment: Как добиться мультиязычной маршрутизации???